# How to load a font from a file in VB and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, fonts

I want to load a font in my VB Form program from a file.

e.g.: My font is in the same folder of my .exe program, and I want it to stay an external resource (that we can replace so that it change the entire program's font).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's and example of how you can do it in C#:

```
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\\Documents and Settings\\somefont.ttf");
System.Drawing.Font font = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12);
label1.Font = font;
```

Or, in VB.NET:

```
Dim privateFonts As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\Documents and Settings\somefont.ttf")
Dim font As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 12)
label1.Font = font
```

Look [THIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx) for more details.

Comment: How can I replace "C:\Documents and Settings\" by the location of the .exe when adding the font (in VB.NET) to get the relative path instead of the absolute ?

Comment: @Che AFAIK if you have the ttf file where your executable is, you just need to write the file name.