# Why doesn't display my bar code?

Tags: vb.net

I try to display a bar code with a String, i Have string like that: SO-123456
but doesn't display my image with bar code.

My code are:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO

Partial Class VB
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim barCode As String = txtCode.Text
        Dim imgBarCode As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image()
        Using bitMap As New Bitmap(barCode.Length * 40, 80)
            Using graphics__1 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap)
                Dim oFont As New Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16)
                Dim point As New PointF(2.0F, 2.0F)
                Dim blackBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
                Dim whiteBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
                graphics__1.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height)
                graphics__1.DrawString("*" & barCode & "*", oFont, blackBrush, point)
            End Using
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                Dim byteImage As Byte() = ms.ToArray()

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
            End Using
            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

And graphics page are:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="VB.aspx.vb" Inherits="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate" 
        onclick="btnGenerate_Click" />
    <hr />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plBarCode" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How get IDAutomationHC39M correctly, can i put in a folder and i try to open that code bar? I have no idea

I want that:
[image]

But i display that:

[image]

Comment: Look now at my code, i put 2 pics to see difference

Comment: I'd say IDAutomationHC39M isn't installed on the place you are running it, needs to be the Fonts folder under Windows.

Comment: If use that on the server where i put my file?

Comment: cand i read this IDAutomationHC39M  from a folder?

Comment: Yes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx to create  PrivateFontCollection and try that.

Comment: Neaa, is hart to generate, i don't know what i miss

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141706/how-to-load-a-font-from-a-file-in-vb-and-c does exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oFont As New Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16)
```

Needs to become

```
Dim privateFonts As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\Documents and Settings\somefont.ttf")
Dim oFont As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 12)
```